# Kqueue (edge-triggered): Does a short read mean that read-readiness was lost?

Tags: c, macos, freebsd, epoll, kqueue

When working with **Linux epoll** in edge triggered mode (`EPOLLET`), and a read/write fails with `EAGAIN`/`EWOULDBLOCK`, it means that read/write-readiness was lost, and that a new readiness event is guaranteed to be made available via `epoll_wait()` as soon as readiness is regained.

Additionally, when working with **Linux epoll** in edge triggered mode, and a nonblocking stream-mode socket, and provided that we registered interest in `EPOLLRDHUP` events, and that an `EPOLLRDHUP` event was not already received, a short read/write (return value less than requested size) also means loss of read/write-readiness, and we can still rely on a new readiness notification when readiness is regained, even though no read/write ever failed with `EAGAIN`/`EWOULDBLOCK`.

Similarly, when working with **Kqueue** (macOS/FreeBSD) in edge triggered mode (`EV_CLEAR`), and a read/write fails with `EAGAIN`/`EWOULDBLOCK`, it means that read/write-readiness was lost, and that a new readiness event is guaranteed to be made available via `kevent()` as soon as readiness is regained.

**Question:** When working with **Kqueue** in edge-triggered mode, and a nonblocking stream-mode socket, and provided that we registered interest in `EV_EOF` events, and that an `EV_EOF` event was not already received, is there a similar guarantee, that a short read/write means loss of read/write-readiness, and that a new readiness event is guaranteed to be produced when readiness is regained?

**EDIT:** Note: Knowing that a short read means loss of read-readiness allows me (in the general case) to avoid a redundant invocation of `read()` just to get the `EAGAIN`/`EWOULDBLOCK` failure.

The meaning of a short read/write in the context of Linux epoll, follows from this comment in `epoll`(7) man page:

> For  stream-oriented  files (e.g., pipe, FIFO, stream socket), the condition that the read/write I/O space is exhausted can also be detected by checking the amount of data read from / written to the target file descriptor.  For example, if you call read(2) by asking to read a certain amount of data and read(2) returns a lower number of bytes, you can be sure of having exhausted the read I/O space for the file descriptor.  The same is true when writing using write(2).  (Avoid this latter technique if you cannot guarantee that the monitored file descriptor always  refers  to  a  stream-oriented file.)

Answer (score 0):

You ask about "**Kqueue** in edge-triggered mode", but the kqueue documentation does not use that terminology.  I think you must mean that you have enabled the `EV_CLEAR` flag for the event in question, with the effect that

> After the event is retrieved by the user, its state is reset.

([BSD documentation for `kqueue()`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=kqueue&sektion=2))

Furthermore, you stipulate that the program has

> registered interest in `EV_EOF` events, and that an `EV_EOF` event was not already received

but `EV_EOF` is not an event in its own right; rather, it is a flag that some of the available filters will set when appropriate, especially `EVFILT_READ`.

Anyway, the core of your question is

> is there a similar guarantee, that a short read/write means loss of read/write-readiness, and that a new readiness event is guaranteed to be produced when readiness is regained?

As far as I can determine, there is no guarantee that a short read signals loss of read readiness, neither for BSD nor for Linux.  Indeed, the Linux docs for `read(2)` specifically call out receipt of a signal as a possible alternative reason for a short read.

Moreover, the usage model the Linux `epoll()` docs recommend for non-blocking file descriptors in edge-triggered mode is to read repeatedly until a read fails with `EAGAIN`, using *that* as the indication of loss of readiness prior to end-of-file.  I recommend following the same policy with the kqueue system for events that have `EV_CLEAR` in effect.

I recognize that you hoped to save one `read()` call by stopping upon a short read, but I think that presents a bona fide risk of the process least of leaving incoming data streams unserviced indefinitely.  Furthermore, your concern is premature unless you've determined that those extra reads are responsible for a measurable, unacceptable performance drain.

Comment: Note that I am assuming nonblocking mode sockets in this question, so a short read due to a signal interruption does not occur, at least not on Linux, and I think generally on any POSIX-like system.

Comment: A short read/write on Linux is guaranteed to mean "loss of read readiness", at least from the point of view of epoll. This is clearly stated in the epoll man page (the section I quoted in my question).

Comment: Note, I am excluding the case where an `EV_EOF` event (an event with that flag set) is either pending, or has been received, because in that case, a short read is always caused by the end of input, rather than loss of read readiness. Similarly for `EPOLLRDHUP` with Linux epoll.